# How to select nodes in XPath which have some attribute?

Tags: c#, xpath

I want to select nodes which have attribute class with some value not specifying tag.

How to do it?

So far I have:

```
html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//[@class='value']");
```

But it's not working good as far as I see it.

For instance, let me have this kind of HTML code:

```
<div>
  <div class="value"></div>
  <a class="value"></div>
</div>
```

it would need to give me back those 2 elements inside of `<div>`, so `<div>` and `<a>`. Is that possible?

Comment: Where is the xpath text?

Comment: "//[@class='value']" ?

Comment: Isn't this answered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248063/xpath-to-select-element-with-attribute-value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include the root node, you can use the `descendant-or-self` access like so:

```
descendant-or-self::*[@class='value']
```

Eliminate `-or-self` if you don't want to consider the root node. More importantly, the asterisk is what is telling the XPath parser to return a node set.

Answer (score 3):

So I believe the correct syntax for what you want is this:

```
html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='value']");
```

When you're looking for just the attribute you don't need the `[ ]` because you're not refining it by element.

Comment: Nop, because it needs to give back nodes.

Comment: @Tommz, I was wondering that while sitting here, please see my edit.

Comment: Yepp, now it's correct, but I need to give to Heath correct answer since he answered correctly first :) Thanks a lot though.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're working with HTML class attributes here, I suggest using the following:

```
//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' value ')]
```

Note the spaces surrounding the value. This will ensure that you find the elements even if they have multiple classes. Simply using `@class='value'` would not work in that situation.