# Xpath to select node value based on another node value

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm quite a novice with Xpath.

Suppose I have an xml catalog to import goods into an e-shop:

```
<categories>
    <category id="26">Jackets</category>
    <category id="27">Jeans</category>
    <category id="28">Sweaters</category>
    <category id="29">Shirts</category>
    ...
</categories>

<goods>
    <good id="123">
        <categoryId>26</categoryId>
        <label>D&G</label>
        <color>Black</color>
        <size>M, XL</size>
    </good>
    ...
<goods>
```

The first part of the catalog is a list of goods' categories, the second part is a list of the goods.
Each good has a `<categoryId>` which value equals the "id" attribute of some `<category>` from the `<categories>` list.

From the code above I need to get a good's description like this: *Category: Jackets; Label: D&G; Color: Black; Size: M, XL.*

**Label**, **Color** and **Size** can be picked directly from the `<good>` context, and it's not the problem. But for the **Category** I have only an id which is 26 and which matches the id of the **Jackets** category from the `<categories>` context.

So my goal is to select the value of the `<category id="26">Jackets</category>` node using the value of the `<categoryId>26</categoryId>` node.

Thank you much.

Comment: What language are you using to do this? C#? PHP? XSLT? Can you show us some code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XPath to select Element with attribute value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248063/xpath-to-select-element-with-attribute-value)

Comment: @JLRishe I use Drupal CMS and Feeds XPath Parser module.

Answer (score 1):

To selected the `category` associated with a `good` that has an `@id` of 123, use this XPath:

```
//categories/category[@id = //goods/good[@id='123']/categoryId]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it works for only one good. The catalog I work with has 1000+ goods, I need something universal which would work for all of them.

Comment: This XPath universally would select the `category` associated with any `good` specified via its `@id`, regardless of the number of `good` elements. '123' was merely an example; use any @id there you'd like.  You did ask to be able to "*select the value of the `<category id="26">Jackets</category>` node using the value of the `<categoryId>26</categoryId>` node.*"  How else would you like to specify the `good` of interest other than via its `@id`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have retrieved the value `26` from the `categoryId` element already, the XPath to select the element with "Jackets" in it would be along the lines of:

```
//categories/category[@id = "26"]
```

Depending on what language you're using, you may need to incorporate that 26 using string concatenation, or in XSLT, you can use a variable in the expression directly:

```
//categories/category[@id = $categoryId]
```

(However, in XSLT, a better approach would be to use keys).