# what's wrong in this html dom php code?

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument

I'm trying to do a code that will print the contents of all the elements with `itemprop="price"` from some link but it don't work, I can't figure out why, this is the code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
$doc      = new DOMDocument();
$allscan  = array(
    'http://www.mobile54.co.il/30786',
    'http://www.mobile54.co.il/35873',
    'http://www.mobile54.co.il/34722'
);
$alllinks = array();
$html     = file_get_contents($allscan[0]);
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$href = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
for ($j = 0; $j < count($allscan); $j++) {
    $html = file_get_contents($allscan[$j]);
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $href = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
    for ($i = 0; $i < $href->length; $i++) {
        $link = $href->item($i)->getAttribute("href");
        $lin  = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', 'http://www.mobile54.co.il' . $link . "<br />");
        if (strpos($link, 'items/') && !strpos($link, '#techDetailsAName')) {
            if (!in_array($lin, $alllinks)) {
                $alllinks[] = $lin;
            }
        }
    }
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($alllinks); $i++) {
    echo $alllinks[$i];
}
for ($i = 0; $i < count($alllinks); $i++) {
    $lin  = "$alllinks[$i]";
    $html = file_get_contents($lin);
    $doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8"?>' . $html);
    $span = $doc->getElementsByTagName('span');
    for ($j = 0; $j < $span->length; $j++) {
        $attr = $span->item($j)->getAttribute('itemprop');
        if ($attr == "price") {
            echo $span->item($j)->textContent . "<br />";
        }
    }
}


?>
```

when I paste "someurl" insted of `$lin` it work but the other way doesn't. I've tried to do `$html = file_get_contents($alllinks[$i]);` but it didn't work, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is probably that you appended a `<br />` to the end of your URL for some reason. But, there are a lot of opportunities to improve your code with use of [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). (Note also that you can just pass a URL directly to the DomDocument object.)

First we pull all the `<a>` elements with [matching attribute values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14248063/1255289). We get the URLs and then search them for elements with the exactly matching `itemprop` attribute, and get the [text content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5033955/1255289) of them.

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.mobile54.co.il/30786";
$prices = [];
$hrefs = [];
$combined = [];

$dom = new DomDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHtmlFile($url);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
// get <a> elements with href containing items/ but not #techDetailsAName
$nodes = $xpath->query("//a[contains(@href, 'items/') and not(contains(@href, '#techDetailsAName'))]/@href");
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $hrefs[] = trim($node->value);
}

// now you have a list of URLs
foreach ($hrefs as $k=>&$href) {
    $href = "http://www.mobile54.co.il$href";
    $dom->loadHtmlFile($href);
    $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
    // get any element with itemprop of price
    $nodes = $xpath->query("//*[@itemprop='price']");
    $prices[$k] = $nodes->item(0)->textContent;
}

// now you have $urls and $prices, combine them:
foreach ($hrefs as $k=>$v) {
    $combined[$k] = [$hrefs[$k], $prices[$k]];
}
print_r($combined);
```

Comment: first of all thanks a lot! it solved the problem, I didn't saw it.
second, I don't really understand your code and I don't know what you did there... how does it better then the other? (faster?)

Comment: You can see that the code is shorter, but also it's simpler to read and it gives better performance. Learning XPath can be tricky but there are lots of references online.

Comment: can you send me one refernce if you know?

Comment: amm can you help me in another thing?

Comment: @mike please improve this question's title to be more indicative of the task and improve searchability.

Comment: @mickmackusa  I'd certainly not answer this question today, although my code is an improvement. Looks like they appended "<br/>" to a URL and then attempted to fetch it with `file_get_contents()`. VTC as typo, I don't think there's much value to this question.