# How to select element missing an attribute value via XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

For example: I want to find the `keywords` without node `id="year"`, and return `"Train"`:

```
<r>
<keywords>
    <node id="family" keyref="Transport"></node>
    <node id="product" keyref="Car"></node>
    <node id="year" keyref="2017"></node>
</keywords>

<keywords>
    <node id="family" keyref="Transport"></node> 
    <node id="product" keyref="Train"></node>       <- FIND THIS
</keywords>

<keywords>
    <node id="family" keyref="Transport"></node>
    <node id="product" keyref="Bike"></node>
    <node id="year" keyref="2017"></node>
</keywords>
</r>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath to select Element by attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248063/xpath-to-select-element-by-attribute-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//node[not(@id="year")]
```

will select all `node` elements that do not have a `@id="year"` attribute value.  You can append `/@keyref` if you only want the `keyref` attribute.

---

This XPath,

```
//keywords[not(node/@id="year")]
```

will select all `keywords` elements that do not have a `node` child element with `@id="year"`.