# how to get a node based on the field name value from xml?

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to get the C node that has the field (name = p and value = 4)

How to get this without using index?

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C>
            <field name="p" value="1"/>
            <field name="q" value="2"/>
        </C>
        <C>
            <field name="p" value="3"/>
            <field name="q" value="4"/>
        </C>
    </B>
</A>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath to select Element by attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248063/xpath-to-select-element-by-attribute-value)

Comment: there is no node `name = p and value = 4` on your example of xml file?

Comment: @KunduK i was referring to  <field name="q" value="4"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following Xpath.

```
//field[@name="q"][@value="4"]/..
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. however I was trying to get the <C> node that has <field name="q" value="4"/>. (editing my question now)

Comment: Edited Try now.

Comment: this did the trick //C//field[@name="q"][@value="4"]/..     pls add this to your solution, so that i can mark it as the answer

Comment: Your question was not clear to me earlier.If you asked that you want get parent tag of given child tag it would have been better.Updated it thanks.