# Finding the ID of a specific element on MS EDGE Settings page

Tags: html, powershell, microsoft-edge

[Console showing Edge Settings page and element I need an ID for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99kUA.jpg)

Hello, I am searching for the specific ID of an edge web browser setting. I am in a unique environment and need to setup automation through PowerShell.

The problem is the element I am using .SendKeys on has no ID so I cannot target it.

Attached image shows the div classes it's in. I have dug through Spiceworks and Stack overflow haven't found anything detailing how to obtain an element ID that's sitting in a class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248063/xpath-to-select-element-by-attribute-value e.g. for the `aria-lable="Downloads button"` attribute

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I read through that example provided so I would use. 

//Employee[@id = 'aria-lable="Downloads button']  

 to select the element that does not have an ID assigned?

My script looks like this: 

$wshell.SendKeys([@id = 'aria-lable="Downloads button'])

Comment: Did what you mentioned work for you?

Comment: @RYANKALTENBACH no nothing like that; I'm confused how you would use wscript.shell's sendkeys method to target an ID in a web browser internals if the switch *did* have an ID?